# mysql_fetch_assoc and JOIN and echo

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables users and msgs:
users contain `id`,`fullname`,`email`,`password`
and messages contains `id`, `sender`, `receiver`, `link`

I want to read all links for the receiver (user `id`) where its equal to the `email`, and `echo` the fullname of the sender and receiver and the link.

Anyone pls, I'm kind of new to this?

```
$sql = mysql_fetch_assoc("SELECT m.sender,m.receiver, m.link, u.fullname, u.email 
                         FROM `users` AS u 
                         JOIN `messages` AS m ON m.receiver = u.id 
                         WHERE u.email = '$email'");

echo $sql['sender'];
```

Comment: share table schema using output of `show create table tablename` query. Also share sample entries in both table.

Comment: where does `$sql` come from?

Comment: This is your second q, I think you need to read more about `mysql_` functions here: php.net/mysql

Comment: Where exactly is your `mysql_fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: i edited the code, as i said there's two table (users and messages)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT m.sender,m.receiver, m.link, u.fullname, u.email 
                     FROM `users` AS u 
                     JOIN `messages` AS m ON m.receiver = u.id 
                     WHERE u.email = '" . $email . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = myslq_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['sender'];
}
```